# double inaccuracy

Tags: java, casting, double

I'm trying to retrieve any digits that come after a decimal point in any given number (below an example number is represented by "in").

```
double in = 1.2;
double out = in - (int)in;
```

Here I expect/want "out" to equate to 0.2 but the number comes out as 0.19999999999999996.   Why is this and how can I get the result I want?

Comment: Read up on floating point representation of numbers - 0.2 is irrational in binary, you'll need to use something that works precisely with decimals to get the result you want.

Comment: read this http://floating-point-gui.de/ then read this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Hey, I get to plug my own web site!  Go to http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/ and enter 1.2 in the box and click on Double.  It should help explain what's going on.

Comment: Your algorithm is not working quite right. The closest double to 1.2 is 1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875

Comment: @EvanKnowles Technically, 0.2 is rational, rather than irrational, regardless of the number radix. It has a non-terminating binary expansion.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan: Somehow you dropped the leading '1.' from 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 (and that is what Adam's tool gives me, which is correct).

Comment: @RickRegan You are right - a copy-paste error.